# Find $x$ that solves $x\left(e^{\frac{a}{x}}-1\right)-y=0$

Tags: special-functions, computer-algebra

When trying to solve the equation in the title with WA, it produced the following as the solution:

[image]

now, if you divide the numerator and denominator by $y$ and set $z:=-\frac{a}{y}$ the solution becomes
$$\frac{a}{W_n(z\,e^z)-z}\ =\ \frac{a}{z-z}\ =\ \frac{a}{0}\ =\ \infty$$

**Questions:**

- can $x\cdot(e^{\frac{a}{x}}-1)-y=0$ be solved for $x$ and can the solution be expressed with the Lambert $W_n$ function resp.
- can the correctness of the result generated by by WA be explained?

Comment: Did you try asking Stephen Wolfram https://www.stephenwolfram.com/?

Comment: @markvs not yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $x'=x/a$, $y'=y/a$, then the real-valued solution to $x'(e^{1/x'}-1)=y'$ is
$$x'=\frac{-y'}{1+y'W_0(-e^{-1/y'}/y')}\;\;\text{for}\;\;0<y'<1,$$
$$x'=\frac{-y'}{1+y'W_{-1}(-e^{-1/y'}/y')}\;\;\text{for}\;\;y'>1.$$
There is no solution for $y'<0$.
A numerical test: for $y'=1/2$ this gives $x'=-0.6275$ and for $y'=2$ this gives $x'=0.795905$, which indeed solves the equation.

---

The "$\infty$" result at the end of the OP appears because
the identification $W_n(ze^z)=z$ is mistaken. (The correct equation is $W_n(z)e^{W_n(z)}=z$.)

Comment: Note $W_n$ with subscripts other than $0,-1$ give us complex solutions.  The OP did not specify real when asking Wolfram Alpha, so it assumed complex.

Comment: indeed, I will remove that line, thanks.